# Athena PowerBI Connector pull data from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi, amazon-athena

I am using ODBC Data Source connector for connecting Athena (Samba) to PowerBI.
We have requirement to show data from Athena into MS Power BI , but in order to do so we need to make S3 buckets public , if I remove public access from S3 buckets. it fails with Authentication failure.

Is it necessary to make S bucket public in this case or what other options i have ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation for the [Athena PowerBI connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-odbc-and-power-bi.html) there is link to [how to set up the permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/policy-actions.html).

Comment: Are you talking about this ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/managed-policies.html#awsquicksightathenaaccess-managed-policy

Comment: It does not talk about whether i need to make S3 bucket public or not. When i don't make S3 bucket public it does not work with access denied.